# Whiteboard resource tool for Linux?

Tags: movesense

Is there of will there be Linux version of whiteboard resource tool (wbres.exe)? Tried to google for it but no luck.

Is it possible to build movesense-device-lib on Linux?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is hardly related to programming. Please read [ask] in order to get going with this community. [The Software Recommendations Stack Exchange Community](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) may be better fitting your question. However, it is hard to tell what you actually mean. What is the name and manufacurer of your whiteboard software? Please consider to contact the manufacturer directly to ask such questions.

Answer (score 1):

The latest update to movesense-device-lib contains now the tools to build on OSX and Linux (We only test actively on Windows though). Please see if it works for you and report any issues in the movesense-device-lib Bitbucket Issues tracker.

*Full disclosure: I work for Movesense team*